# Searching and deleting registry entries using wildcards

Tags: powershell, registry

Is it possible to search for a wildcard - example `*WAAgent*` or `*WAHost*` and delete every registry key that references that wildcard statement above?

Answer (score 8):

You may try something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\ -Recurse -Include *WAAgent* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\ -Recurse -Include *WAHost* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item
```

You have to specify in `-Path` if they are location in HKLM(local machine) or HKCU(current user), as they are two different drives. This has to be run as admin, and will give lots of errors(that's why I used `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to hide them).

**CAUTION:** Personally I don't think it's smart to be using wildcards in registry though since it may delete something you didn't know about that could crash the system. My recommendation would be to compile a list of paths to the keys you want to remove and loop through it with foreach to delete one by one. Again, wildcards are DANGEROUS in registry.

Answer (score 3):

If you are searching for a property value instead of a key value (and delete the relative key) you can use something like this:

```
gci HKLM: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
    -match "WAAGent") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item
```

Like for the @Graimer's answer, **BE CAREFULL!!!**

Comment: Had a warning there myself, but made it a little clearer now. Registry is not a place for wildcards in my eyes. He should get a list of keys and run them through a foreach-loop instead.

Comment: @Graimer Replaced de 'As' with 'Like', maybe wasn't clear to be carefull also using my code ;)

Answer (score 2):

As all have already suggested, use this with extremely caution!! The following will go through all registry hives. Keep in mind that a matching key found can have a deep structure underneath it and you're deleting it all. Remove the WhatIf switch to actually delete the keys.

```
Get-ChildItem Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry:: -Include *WAAgent*,*WAHost* -Recurse |
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that there was a Session ID in the path of the registry.
To solve this is got the first part of the registry, stored it in a variable and used this for my foreach loop where the keys for drive mappings were stored.

The above was too rigorous in my case.

The below shows an example to remove (local) drive mappings in a session (the problem i had).

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 20

# This stores the Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SessionInfo\<SESSIONID>"
$SessionInfo = Get-Item "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SessionInfo\*"

cd "HKCU:\"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

$Items = Get-ChildItem "$SessionInfo\MyComputer\Namespace"

foreach($Item in $Items){

        Remove-Item $Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose

}
```